# Verilog Best Practice - Incrementing a variable

Tags: verilog

I'm by no means a Verilog expert, and I was wondering if someone knew which of these ways to increment a value was better. Sorry if this is too simple a question.

Way A:

In a combinational logic block, probably in a state machine:

```
//some condition
count_next = count + 1;
```

And then somewhere in a sequential block:

```
count <= count_next;
```

Or Way B:
Combinational block:

```
//some condition
count_en = 1;
```

Sequential block:

```
if (count_en == 1)
  count <= count + 1;
```

I have seen Way A more often. One potential benefit of Way B is that if you are incrementing the same variable in many places in your state machine, perhaps it would use only one adder instead of many; or is that false?

Which method is preferred and why? Do either have a significant drawback?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> One potential benefit of Way B is that if you are incrementing the same variable in many places in your state machine, perhaps it would use only one adder instead of many; or is that false?

Any synthesis tool will attempt automatic resource sharing. How well they do so depends on the tool and code written. Here is a document that describes some features of [Design Compiler](http://acms.ucsd.edu/info/documents/dc/dcrmo.pdf). Notice that in some cases, less area means worse timing.

> Which method is preferred and why? Do either have a significant drawback?

It depends. Verilog(for synthesis) is a means to implement some logic circuit but the spec does not specify exactly how this is done. Way A may be the same as Way B on an FPGA but Way A is not consistent with low power design on an ASIC due to the unconditional sequential assignment. Using reset nets is almost a requirement on an ASIC but since many FPGAs start in a known state, you can save quite a bit of resources by not having them.

Comment: You should use what your synthesis tool documentation recommends.

Answer (score 1):

I use Way A in my Verilog code. My sequential blocks have almost no logic in them; they just assign registers based on the values of the "wire regs" computed in the combinational always blocks. There is just less to go wrong this way. And with Verilog we need all the help we can get.

Answer (score 1):

What is your definition of "better" ? 
It can be better performance (faster maximum frequency of the synthesized circuit),  smaller area (less logic gates), or faster simulation execution.

Let's consider smaller area case for Xilinx and Altera FPGAs. Registers in those FPGA families have *enable* input. In your "Way B", *count_en* will be directly mapped into that *enable* register input, which will result in less logic gates. Essentially, "Way B" provides more "hints" to a synthesis tool how to better synthesize that circuit. Also it's possible that  most FPGA synthesis tools (I'm talking about Xilinx XST, Altera MAP, Mentor Precision, and Synopsys Synplify) will correctly infer register *enable* input from the "Way A".

If *count_en* is synthesized as *enable* register input, that will result in better performance of the circuit, because your counter increment logic will have less logic levels.

Thanks

Comment: I'm not certain I understand what you mean. It seems to me the count_en signal will be enabling the Adder, not the register itself. Could you explain further? Thank you.